# Awesome WM loads personal rc.lua but then overwrites with system settings

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, awesome

I just started playing with awesome-wm. Sometimes, when I reload my config, the settings hold. Other times, I can see some settings take for a second, but then are overridden by the defaults.

I copied the /etc/xdg/awesome directory to ~/.config/awesome as suggested on the [wiki](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/My_first_awesome). I've also noticed some other issues with these steps, and I'm not sure if it's me, my system, or what. Other relevant issues include:

- Theme loads, and then loads the default
- Network Widget on the link above doesn't load (or I don't see it)
- Changing the tags results in 18 tags. The ones I changed, and 1-9 again.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?